# How to use two-way Data binding within ngFor of array of objects (differ with key-value pairs)?

Tags: angular6

I have tried two-way data binding inside ngFor loop which consists of array of objects but i am unable for differentiate the input fields with [(ngModel)].

```
     <div class="content-box" *ngFor="let content of contentList; let i = 
                             index;trackBy:trackByIndex;">
        <div class="drag-icon">
            <i class="material-icons">reorder</i>
        </div>
        <textarea *ngIf="content.type === 'text'" 
                  [(ngModel)]="content.text" 
                  placeholder="Type Here"></textarea>
        <div *ngIf="content.type === 'button'" class="text-center">
            <button type="button" class="btn-automsg">{{content?.button}} 
            </button>
            <label class="label-block">{{content?.block}}</label>
        </div>
        <div class="delete-icon">
            <i class="material-icons" 
               (click)="deleteBox(i)">delete_outline</i>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: can you share the structure of your data

Comment: Like this [ { "text" : "new" , "type" : "text" }, { "text" : "menu" , "type" : "button" } ]

Comment: In the above array, if the object contains type( text ) should be two data binding and other types should be string interpolation.

Answer (score 0):

In you code, i changed

- `<button type="button" class="btn-automsg">{{content?.button}} </button>`
- into `<button type="button" class="btn-automsg">{{content?.text}} </button>`

... which i what i think you were aiming for.

check the relevant **HTML**, in the *ngFor loop, printing the contents of each row so that we can see the text changing as a result of `[(ngModel)]`:

```
<div class="content-box" *ngFor="let content of contentList; let i = 
                             index;trackBy:trackByIndex;">
    Type:<mark>{{content.type}}</mark> - Text:<mark>{{content.text}}</mark>
    <div class="drag-icon">
        <i class="material-icons">reorder</i>
        </div>
        <textarea *ngIf="content.type === 'text'" 
                  [(ngModel)]="content.text" 
                  placeholder="Type Here"></textarea>
        <div *ngIf="content.type === 'button'" class="text-center">
            <button type="button" class="btn-automsg">{{content?.text}} 
            </button>
            <label class="label-block">{{content?.block}}</label>
        </div>
        <div class="delete-icon">
            <i class="material-icons" 
               (click)="deleteBox(i)">delete_outline</i>
        </div>
    </div>
```

if there is confusion, perhaps you can suggest changes to the [attached stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fuzzgi) so that i can help

Comment: Anyway i found that problem, because of your stackblitz example

Comment: the problem is i was pushed the additional elements through a variable like elementNew =  { "text" :"new", "type" : "text" } ;this.contentList.push(this.elementNew) instead of this.contentList.push({ "text" :"new", "type" : "text" }) to avoid conflict.